# A certificate contains an unknown extension that is marked "critical."

Tags: certificates, windows

I recently got my digital certificate to sign my software.

Today I signed my first piece of software, it all went well until, I got the error, "A certificate contains an unknown extension that is marked "critical.""

When I check if the signature is fine, you know on properties in Windows.

I am in need of help, how can i fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: It's going to be extremely hard to help you -- beyond vague generalities -- without lots more specific information. Where did you get the cert, and what kind is it? Where and how are you trying to use it, and when exactly does the error appear? Can you list its properties (especially, what extensions it includes) (note that you may want to remove identifying information from it).

Comment: What is happening: the message informs you that the CA has added a "critical" extension to your cert. Extensions are extra information added to the certificate. Critical extensions need to be understood for the specific software you are using, if not, the softwarte needs to refuse the certificate, as described in RFC5280. 

How to fix: Depends: We need to understand what is the extension, why it is there and why the software you are using to sing the code does not recognize it.